# Limiting battery charge level

Tags: battery

I have a dell laptop which allows setting custom charge level. What I want to know is that if I set it to be between 50% to 80% and then continue to use it on A.C then will it stop charging and battery will remain at 80% or will it stop charging at 80% then decrease till it reaches at 50% and then charges again

Comment: why not try it? Doesn't seem to be difficult and you get a 100% real answer.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We expect you to attempt to answer your own question before posting here. This is something you can try yourself.

Answer (score -1):

If you set a cap at 80% it just won't charge any further than that and will keep using AC power. Constant charge cycling would diminish the battery capacity very fast so it not done.